# How to pass a DATE_SUB() as a parameter in update query in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am updating a field with another field which is datetime(datatype), So while updating it should be a minute less So i am using DATE_SUB(). But i am getting  error `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` near `INTERVAL`

code:

```
for(var k=0;k<grouppedArray[i][j].length;k++){
    if(grouppedArray[i][j][k+1]){
        db.query('update userRegister set  logout= ? where userId = ? and catId = ?', [SUBDATE(grouppedArray[i][j][k+1].login, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE), 1, grouppedArray[i][j][k].userId, grouppedArray[i][j][k].catId], function (err, updatedLogout) {

        }
    }
}
```

Where am i going wrong here? Please help

Comment: You forgot a `)` for closing `db.query()` function

Comment: @Cid I missed ) in above code. Even with ) i get  same error

Comment: `[SUBDATE(grouppedArray[i][j][k+1].login, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE), 1, grouppedArray[i][j][k].userId, grouppedArray[i][j][k].catId]` you have 1 parameter in excess

Comment: @Cid yeah, but even if i fix it still getting same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following :

```
for(var k=0;k<grouppedArray[i][j].length;k++){
    if(grouppedArray[i][j][k+1]){
        db.query('update userRegister set  logout= SUBDATE(?, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) where userId = ? and catId = ?', [grouppedArray[i][j][k+1].login, grouppedArray[i][j][k].userId, grouppedArray[i][j][k].catId], function (err, updatedLogout) {

        }
    }
}
```

or

```
for(var k=0;k<grouppedArray[i][j].length;k++){
    if(grouppedArray[i][j][k+1]){
        db.query('update userRegister set  logout= ? - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE where userId = ? and catId = ?', [grouppedArray[i][j][k+1].login, grouppedArray[i][j][k].userId, grouppedArray[i][j][k].catId], function (err, updatedLogout) {

        }
    }
}
```